# How to stop a innerHtml table repeating itself over and over and over again?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, for-in-loop

I have made an array with objects that get there info from three different user variables, however on one of these there are many sub variables that i don't want it to repeat itself every time the user presses the select button(which updates the table) instead i want it to just add onto (or take away) from the sections that it already has in the table. thanks(if you need the variable code let me know) please help!! i really need a solution!!

```
//creating array
var gProducts = new Array();
var gTotalCost = 0;



// Adding Products to array gProducts
    function addProduct
{
var product = new Object();
product.name = name;
product.cost = cost;
gProducts.push(product);
gTotalCost += parseInt(cost)
}


 //Getting products from array, use of for in loop setting new table rows in blank var for each array item
function renderProducts()
{
var HTMLadd = ""

for (var i in gProducts)
{
if( gProducts[i].cost > 0){
    HTMLadd = HTMLadd + 
    "<tr>"+ 
    "<td class='tableSettings00' id=tableRow2 >" + gProducts[i].name +
    "</td>"+
    "<td class='tableSettings'>€<span id=tableRow2part2>" + gProducts[i].cost +
    "</span></td>"+ 
    "</tr>";
    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
document.getElementById('tableRow').innerHTML = HTMLadd;

}
```

Comment: Is this a google-translated question? I can understand every single word, but I've no idea, what they mean when put together like this.

Comment: I don't know what `getElementById('tableRow')` is, but it sounds like a table row. It's not wise to replace its inner HTML with a bunch of other table rows. You will make your HTML invalid.

Comment: You shouldn't use a "for in" loop with an array. That may account for part of it. Instead use `for (var i = 0; i < gProducts.length; i++){}`

Comment: Also, it's not wise to add an id like `tableRow2` and `tableRow2part2` to elements which you create in a loop. An element id should be unique thoughout the page.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking. Can you create a sample at http://jsfiddle.net to better explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: tableRow = body of the table and no it is not translated! and i using a for loop before it didn't help and it is unique its the only one of that being used in all docs (JS, HTML, CSS)

Comment: Hmm... Setting literally for example `id=tableRow2` creates multiple elements with the same `id` in the loop, hence the `id`s are not unique. Setting `innerHTML` of a table is not a way to create rows to a table (it doesn't work in IEs at all), use [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) and [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell) methods instead. To remove rows, you can use [`deleteRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.deleteRow) method.

Comment: okay i have done that however it has not solved the problem the elements in the table still repeat themselves, even more now than before!

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you always iterate through the whole `gProducts`, hence the values already placed to the table are doubled every time you execute the function.

This example uses some methods in [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) to create new rows and cells. It also has a counter (`index`) holding the starting position of each iteration.

```
var index = 0; // Counter for holding the current position in gProducts

function renderProducts () {
    var n, row, cell, span;        
    for (n = index; n < gProducts.length; n++) { // Start looping from the first new index in gProducts
        if (gProducts[n].cost > 0) {
            row = table.insertRow(-1); // Inserts a row to the end of table
            cell = row.insertCell(-1); // Inserts a cell to the end of the newly-created row
            cell.className = 'tableSettings00'; // Sets class for the cell
            cell.id = 'tableRow' + index; // Sets an unique id for the cell
            cell.innerHTML = gProducts[n].name; // Sets the content for the cell
            cell = row.insertCell(-1); // Create another cell to row
            cell.className = 'tableSettings';
            cell.id = 'tableRowPart' + index;
            cell.innerHTML = '€';
            span = document.createElement('span'); // Creates an empty span element
            span.id = 'tableRow2part' + index; // Sets an unique id for span
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(gProducts[n].cost)); // Appends some text to the span
            cell.appendChild(span); // Appends the span to the cell
        }
    }
    index = n; // Sets counter equal to the length of gProducts
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKf65/1/).

As a sidenote, personally I prefer not to use `id`s for elements within a table. If `id`s are needed, you probably have constructed your table incorrectly, or the data is not suitable being shown in a table.

You can use indices and `table.rows` and `rows.cells` collections to find cells, and if some elements has to be searched for from a cell, use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling` properties of a cell to find them.

Comment: okay thanks, but how would i add a way to remove rows after adding them?

Comment: I've updated [the example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKf65/2/), now each row contains a remove button.